# Perl Regex Ban Log

Tags: regex, perl

I want to be able to match all of the following strings to my regex below. It doesnt seem to be working. Any suggestions?

Strings to compare :

```
5878ce43aa3f1e1d713427d118115310 -1 Script Kiddie <perm>
f939f88b50fa5f0099b6751e7be27761 -1 Hacking <perm>
468f6634c5a9b00b5b3872dd6437143f 1356474103 Being Annoying <7day>
```

This is my perl code. It isnt working at the moment. Any suggestions?

```
my $bn_re = q{(.+?) (\d+) (.+?)};
```

Comment: That's your "perl code"? It looks to be "working" just fine. Its a string, and it does what strings do, its being a string. What did you expect it to do? You should be more specific with what you have done and what was not working.

Comment: `\d+` doesn't match `-1`. Did you expect it to?

Comment: Define "isn't working". What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am not entirely sure but it seems you want to split the HASH, the number after, and the name without the amount at the end ?

Comment: The regex wont match my strings is what i ment.

Comment: @user2202426 do you expect it to? What would match the `-` in `-1`? Certainly not the `\d+`

Comment: Regular expressions are not strings, and strings are not regular expressions. Please learn the difference between the two.

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: [It's not working](http://tlp-perl.blogspot.se/2013/06/its-not-working.html) is a poor description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$bn_re =~ /[0-9a-z]+?\s[-0-9]+\s[\w\s]+?[<>a-z0-9]+?/i
```

Answer (score 6):

If the first two fields are always without whitespace in them, you can use `split` to great effect, using the LIMIT option to only get three fields:

```
my ($str, $num, $other) = split ' ', $_, 3;
```

That is, assuming you read the file something like this:

```
while (<>) {
    ... # your code here
}
```

Also, this:

```
my $bn_re = q{(.+?) (\d+) (.+?)};
```

is not a regex. You may be confusing `q()` with `qr()`. You may also be confusing the functionality of

```
$str =~ $bn_re;
```

Which will automagically include the regex in a match operator `m//`. But you should use `qr()`. The `q()` operator does what the single quote does.

Also, you should be aware that `.+?` will match a single char if you allow it. As it does at the end of your "regex". At the end of your string, either do

```
... (.+)/    # matching greedily 
... (.+?)$/  # using anchor to end of string
```

Comment: You're welcome. If your question is answered, you can accept an answer by clicking the checkmark.