# Matching Regex to string

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to match the following string to a regex.

```
13:39:23 BattlEye Server: (Global) Kail: !rpt Guy Breaking Rules
```

Here is what I have for a regex (Which is not working)

```
my $rpt_req1 = q{(\d+):(\d+):(\d+) BattlEye Server: \((.*?)\) (.*?): ^rpt (.*?) (.*?)};
```

Comment: You had a great answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/17505218/342740 but you're still doing it wrong ;(

Comment: You seem to have a `^` where you mean to have a `!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simple expression I could come up from your question

`(\d+):(\d+):(\d+) BattlEye Server: \(\w+\) \w+: !rpt \w+ \w+ \w+`

Try [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com) for validating your regex

Comment: I seem to be able to match this with
`(\d+):(\d+):(\d+) BattlEye Server: \((.*?)\) (.*?): (.+)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regular expression here. If you split on space you'll have a very useful array to work with.